# Plotly.js - Reversing the horizontal bar chart in plotly

Tags: bar-chart, plotly

I am new to plotly and am working of a bar chart example. What I want to do is have the bar chart run from right to left. Here is a link to my jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ksaluja/w0cx3sw1/1/

Currently it is going the default way from right to left. Thanks!

index.html

```
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```

scripts.js

```
var data = [{
  type: 'bar',
  x: [20, 14, 23],
  y: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  orientation: 'h'
}];

Plotly.newPlot('tester', data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `autorange: reversed` property of `xaxis` in `layout` object.

Refer the below example.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**JS:**

```
var data = [{
  type: 'bar',
  x: [20, 14, 23],
  y: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  orientation: 'h'
}];

var layout = {
    xaxis:{
        autorange:'reversed'
    },
    yaxis:{
      side:'right'
    }
}

Plotly.newPlot('tester', data, layout);
```

**References:**

1. [Plotly reversed axis](https://plot.ly/python/axes/#reversed-axes)
2. [Plotly Autorange](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-autorange)

Comment: Thanks so much! I also was trying to reverse the axis labels so that they would be right justified, rather than starting with at the left.

Comment: @KellyRoper Please mention all the requirements :) , can you please check my updated answer!

Comment: Thank you so much!