# How to create arabic charts ? (x-axis from right to left) with Plotly

Tags: python, graph, charts, plotly

I want to start plotting on the x-axis from right to left (for arabic charts). So I need the (x, y) = (0, 0) on the bottom right.
Is it possible to do it on python with plotly? And how ?

Comment: Is this a matplotlib or plotly question?

Comment: can you do it with plotly ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This seems to be a plotly question, can you check the above comment, can we make it a valid question again?

Comment: @NarenMurali I reopened and modified the tags. I suppose this has also already been asked for plotly, so maybe you find an existing duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotly.js - Reversing the horizontal bar chart in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201532/plotly-js-reversing-the-horizontal-bar-chart-in-plotly)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Found it

Comment: Good job, unfortunately I cannot close the same question twice (Ideally I would have known this duplicate beforehance, because replacing duplicates is allowed), so the review queue needs to take care of that now.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest No problem, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @McAlixter Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201532/plotly-js-reversing-the-horizontal-bar-chart-in-plotly), your issue will be resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Plotly Package with Python :

Suppose that we have a normal graph (actual graph, actual yaxis1-left, actual yaxis2-right, actual xaxis), we need to place the actual yaxis1-left on the right side, and the actual yaxis2-right on the left side, and invert the xaxis.
To do this we use the code :

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py

trace1=go.Bar(
                    x=[#Your years here],
                    y=[#Your data here],
                    name = 'chart1'
                )

trace2=go.Scatter(
                    x=[#your years here],
                    y=[#your data here],
                    name = 'chart2',
                    yaxis='y2'
)


data = [trace1, trace2]

layout = go.Layout(
    title="MAIN_TITLE",
    xaxis=dict(title="years",
    autorange='reversed',
    ),


    yaxis=dict(
        title='title1',
        side='right',
        showline=True
    ),


    yaxis2=dict(
        title='title2',
        side='left',
        showline=True
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.plot(fig, filename='axes-reversed.html')
```

I wish this will helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

use decreasing x axis parameters.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.01, 5.0, 0.01)
s = np.exp(-t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlim(5, 0)  # decreasing time

plt.xlabel('decreasing time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('Should be growing...')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```